# Who am I when loading an X509Certificate2?

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, x509certificate2

I have a .NET web application that uses an X509Certificate2 to access a web service. When the application is started, the first request works, but subsequent requests fail, even for the same actual request.

The failure is `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`. An inspection of Wireshark shows that the remove host return a TLSv1 Certificate and then communications cease, which suggest something is wrong with my program.

The subsequent request are Ajax requests from the web interface.

I also have a console program that is able to do multiple requests to the web service, with no issue, so I suspect there is an issue with the certificate that is loaded.

Even though the subsequent accesses are able to load the X509Certificate2, I would like to verify the user that is accessing the certificate.

Initially, I had the certificate loading from my computer account, however, I've also placed a copy in the Local Machine store, and have tried using that as well. I want to verify that permissions to the private key portion of the certificate are not an issue, by comparing the user that accesses the certificate for the first load vs the user that accesses the certificate for subsequent loads.

What c# calls do I make to determine the user that is loading the certificate, so I can compare this with the first request that works, the subsequent requests that don't and the permissions I see via Manage Private Keys in the MMC?

Comment: If you aren't impersonating an account then it should be your application pool account.

Comment: I am impersonating an account, and I think `Environment.UserDomanName`, `Environment.UserName` and `Environment.MachineName` are what I need. Unfortunately, they are showing the same things for the successful and failed requests. I need to find more detail on why the SSL connection is failing.

Comment: Not an answer to my question, but an answer to my underlying issue. By logging System.Net (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5985497/343614), I was able to locate an Algorithm Mismatch. The particular webservice accessed uses Tls, however, other web services were using Ssl3 and Tls12. The setting of the Service Point Manager Protocol was resulting in my particular web service being no longer able to negotiate connections using Tls.