# Does C# HttpClient ignore SSL certificate errors?

Tags: java, c#, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, dotnet-httpclient

We have an internal web service hosted on https with an authorized root CA. When I tried to call that service from Java Apache HttpClient, it gave me the cert error "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

Using SSL tools, I found out that the web service is sending the cert chain without the intermediate cert and it contains only server cert. So the Java cert error made sense because, only the root CA is present in Java truststore and it is unable to verify the cert chain, hence the error.

But on the other hand, I can call the same web service using C# HttpClient (.Net 4.6.1) without any issues.

Is C# HttpClient ignoring the cert issues with the web service or is it downloading the missing cert? Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: No it doesn't ignore them .... unless you configure it to ignore them.   Use this to work out what is actually going on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977817/debugging-failing-https-webrequest

Comment: C# uses the Windows certificate store, is it possible the relevant certificate is in that certificate store?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out with very helpful comments from Stephen and Mark. I set up the trace in app.config where I found that C# HttpClient could find the intermediate certificate.

"System.Net Information: 0 : [23580] SecureChannel#41622463 - Remote certificate was verified as valid by the user."

But I had already verified that the intermediate cert wasn't present in Windows cert store which had led to this confusion. I checked there again and turns out the cert was under My User Account and not Computer Account. It must have been installed there when our company desktops were set up.

Now I am not really sure about the difference between the usage of these two cert stores in Windows, but at least I understand how C# client found the cert.